# Microsoft Word 2010 equations big/large operators appearance

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, equations

Is there any way that I can force MS Word 2010 to show large operators (such as generic sum, integral, etc.) with its limits written below and above its symbol (e.g. Sigma) in situations where it automatically converts it to "inline" format?

I want to achieve this: [image: 1]

In situations like this: [image: 2]

I know that this form might look better in a sentence but if the large operator is for example in a numerator of a fraction MS Word also converts it to the inline form, while I want to use the full non-inline form.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Actually no, I've read this before posting this question and I didn't find my answer there. They say about possible solutions if the equation is in its separate line or paragraph or table cell which in my case isn't.

Comment: That thread asks the same question and the answer tells you what's possible.

Comment: However, I pointed out that the same change of formatting happens when a large operator is in a numerator of a fraction (even if this fraction is in its separate line/table cell etc.). This is obviously very undesirable unlike the situations where one puts an equation between words of a sentence.

Comment: You can easily select any equation and click the down-arrow next to it to switch between *Change to Display* and *Change to Inline*. Is this what you're asking? If not, provide screenshots.

Comment: Switching to "Change to Display" puts the equation in a seperate line and this is not what i want. I want the limits of the generic sum operator below and above the "sigma" in a situation like this: [link](http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/255/95156780.png)

Comment: Apparently *Change limit locations* does not work in fractions. You can select the entire fraction, right-click and change to *Linear Fraction* to obtain [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/px7RZ.png). That's the best you can do IMO.